# Chutzpah adding multiple team build file specifications

Tags: code-coverage, tfsbuild, chutzpah

Is there a way with Chutzpah to specify multiple test specification file sources when running the JS unit tests via Team Build?

I understand that I can add multiple test sources in the build definition.  The major downside to this is it generates a code coverage file for each source, overwriting the code coverage file for each configured test source.  I would like to be able to produce one code coverage report for all tests in the project.  I should be able to accomplish this by reorganizing the source for the project or changing the file pattern we use to identify tests (*_test.js) so it is unique, but I was hoping to avoid these if possible.

Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Chutzpah.json file? This lets you specify multiple test files to run.

```
{
    "Tests": [
        { "Includes": ["*test1*"] },
        { "Path": "Dir3/test.js"},
        { "Path": "Dir1", "Includes": ["*.js"], "Excludes": ["*test4.js"] },
        { "Path": "Dir2" }
    ]
}
```

from 
https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/tests-setting

Comment: I use the chutzpah.json file and it woks great when running the tests in Visual Studio.  How do you use chutzpah.json when running the tests from Team Build?